# img's using srcset do not change at the given width

Tags: css, image, responsive, srcset

I am adding a image to my site that will need to be different dimensions based on the resolution of the screen (pretty common).

What is tripping me up however, is the images that I have set in `<img srcset="X">` are not changing at the given widths.

*(quick note, I use incogento in chrome so this is not the FAMOUS cache issue)*

anyway - on with the show:

Several images (specifically sized)

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
<img src="im2/1280.jpg"
    srcset="im2/120.jpg 120w, 
            im2/320.jpg 320w, 
            im2/640.jpg 640w,
            im2/1280.jpg 1280w,
            im2/1920.jpg 1920w"
    sizes="(max-width: 250px) 120px,
           (max-width: 480px) 320px,
           (max-width: 720px) 640px,
           (max-width: 1400px) 1280px,
           (max-width: 2000px) 1920px,
    " 
    alt="Image description">
```

So based on my above code I would expect that the first image would be 120.jpg (if the screen was under 250px wide) - however:

[image]

First is 320px

[image]

at 460px it shows the image for 1280px

[image]

My guess is that I have missed some key bit of info on how this works.

if anyone can shed some light on this that would be great.

Thanks in advance -
Wally

Answer (score 0):

A great article to read about this topic can be found here (its next level at explaining how the picture and srcset tag should be used)

https://alligator.io/html/picture-element/

Short answer is that images tags `<img>` that use srcset `<img srcset="X">` will be given a width of the image for the browser to decide what to do with `<img srcset="X.jpg 200w">`

BUT IT IS THE BROWSER that decides what image to use based off the values given.

I.e.

```
<img srcset="X.jpg 1000w">
```

The browsers might use that on a display that is 400px wide

For specific images to be used at specific screen sizes then refer to the linked article which gives all the info required.